# Setting even shadow to added image

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm using fabric.js to manipulate images added to my canvas. I have a shadow but I'd like it to be even around the image. What I have now is below, but [here's what I'm trying to replicate with the images added](http://jsfiddle.net/5KKQ2/2564/). What am I doing wrong that's causing the shadow to not display?

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(f) {
    var data = f.target.result;
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function(img) {

      //create shadow
      var shadow = {
        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
        blur: 20,
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 0,
        opacity: 0.6,
        fillShadow: true,
        strokeShadow: true
      }

      var oImg = img.set({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        angle: 0,
        stroke: '#222',
        strokeWidth: 40
      }).scale(0.2);
      oImg.setShadow(shadow); //set shadow
      canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
        format: 'png',
        quality: 1
      });
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});

oImg.setShadow(shadow);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file">
<br />
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If uploaded image is a png, it will show effect to the borders, for others it will effect to border, you can use `affectStroke` which will affect to stroke as well. Here is the [doc](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Shadow.html).

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(f) {
    var data = f.target.result;
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function(img) {

      //create shadow
      var shadow = {
        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
        blur: 20,
        offsetX: 20,
        offsetY: 20,
        affectStroke: true
      }

      var oImg = img.set({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 10
      }).scale(0.2);
      oImg.setShadow(shadow); //set shadow
      canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
        format: 'png',
        quality: 1
      });
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file">
<br />
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: I see, so there is no way to have this be applied evenly like in the linked example?

Comment: My apologies, I removed the offset and increased the blur size which seems to work!

Comment: @codeforever if you remove the offset, also default value is 0 for both offsetX and offsetY. You can check the doc, I shared in answer.

Comment: Okay, I will check it out. It will let me award the bounty in 2 hours. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your shadow is actually displayed, its right behind the object.
If you change offsetX or offsetY you will see it.
Like here

```
var shadow = {
    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
    blur: 20,    
    offsetX: 50,
    offsetY: 50,
    opacity: 0.6,
    fillShadow: true, 
    strokeShadow: true 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5KKQ2/2565/

There is also an issue https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/1214 about shadow size but it's not completed yet.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, that does appear to be the case! So you don't think there's a way to achieve an even shadow around the uploaded photo, like in the rectangle example?

Comment: Seems we can control only 
shadowOffsetX
shadowOffsetY
shadowColor
shadowBlur
these properties. So, I suggest you to write to the issue on Github that you are interested in this feature, maybe maintainers of fabricjs will implement it, otherwise think about changing the conception of your task, maybe you can implement something similar but it will be easier.